# Why i can't use this in header?

Tags: jquery

I can't use the script in header, Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="javascript:void" class="sl-start">Click Here</a> 
<p class="slide" style="display: none">Something to display</p>

<script>
    $(".sl-start").click(function () {
    $(".slide").show();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works here - http://jsbin.com/uxirin/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your code in a document.ready event handler like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sl-start").one('click', function () {
                $(".slide").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="javascript:void" class="sl-start">Click Here</a> 
<p class="slide" style="display: none">Something to display</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Or else, the script will get executed before the element exists!

Comment: Thanks, is this possible to remove the href after displayed the function ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the DOM isn't ready yet in the head for which to attach the event.

If you make it run when the `document`'s ready event fires it'll work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sl-start").click(function () {
        $(".slide").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in the <head> area then you have to use the $(document).ready() event.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".sl-start").click(function () {
            $(".slide").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or the shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

Because the $(document).ready() event is triggered **after** the HTML/CSS documents have been read. Which means the browser is already aware of the **full** content & structure of the HTML document.

Otherwise the HTML structure is not available (has not been fully read yet) so your jQuery calls will fail to find any objects.